# parse string contains time of day

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, exception, timespan

I try to cast a string to time span but i get the following exception :

> Input string was not in a correct format.

My code :

```
rad_from_time.SelectedTime = TimeSpan.Parse(pro[0].FromTime)
```

---

```
pro[0].FromTime = "9:30 AM";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
rad_from_time.SelectedTime = DateTime.ParseExact(pro[0].FromTime, "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 9):

"9:30 AM" is not a TimeSpan. It represents a time, which is part of a whole `DateTime`.

You should use `DateTime` for parsing not `TimeSpan`

```
rad_from_time.SelectedTime = DateTime.ParseExact(pro[0].FromTime, "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
```

read more about [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)